# Keep a jquery Dialog inside a tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

I have some tabs. And in one tab I want to open many dialogs. But if the user changes of tab, I want those dialogs to stay in the other tab. Whats is happening now, is that if the user switch tabs the dialog are always at top.

Any idea how to keep a dialog inside a Div always?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on a tab, JQuery simply hides all tab contents (div's) and shows the selected div. So you have to synchronize the dialog show/hide based on which tab you want to show the dialog.

Show the dialog(s), When the user click on the tab that has the dialog and close them when they navigate to other tabs.

You can use `select: function(event, ui) { ... }` JQuery Tab function to show/hide the dialog.

[Link to JQuery Tabs select event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select)

[Link to JQuery Dialog method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Good Luck :)

Comment: A new possibility is available as of jQuery-UI 1.10: the `appendTo` option of the Dialog widget lets you specify which element the dialog widget gets appended to (default: `<body>`). If you append the dialog elements to a `ui-tabs-panel` div or any of its descendents, it will get hidden when the tab is hidden/deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

You could close the dialog on the click event of each tab. You'll have to find some way to indicate the dialog was opened and on which tab so that when that tab is clicked again, the dialog box will open. You could probably just add a class to the dialog div when it's closed that matches up to the tab name or something to that effect.